# Async/Await with a WinForms ProgressBar

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I've gotten this type of thing working in the past with a BackgroundWorker, but I want to use the new async/await approach of .NET 4.5. I may be barking up the wrong tree. Please advise.

**Goal**: Create a component that will do some long-running work and show a modal form with a progress bar as it's doing the work. The component will get the handle to a window to block interaction while it's executing the long-running work.

**Status**: See the code below. I thought I was doing well until I tried interacting with the windows. If I leave things alone (i.e. don't touch!), everything runs "perfectly", but if I do so much as click on either window the program hangs after the long-running work ends. Actual interactions (dragging) are ignored as though the UI thread is blocked.

**Questions**: Can my code be fixed fairly easily? If so, how? Or, should I be using a different approach (e.g. BackgroundWorker)?

**Code** (Form1 is a standard form with a ProgressBar and a public method, UpdateProgress, that sets the ProgressBar's Value):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting..");
        var mgr = new Manager();
        mgr.GoAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("..Ended");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Manager
{
    private static Form1 _progressForm;

    public async void GoAsync()
    {
        var owner = new Win32Window(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
        _progressForm = new Form1();
        _progressForm.Show(owner);

        await Go();

        _progressForm.Hide();
    }

    private async Task<bool> Go()
    {
        var job = new LongJob();
        job.OnProgress += job_OnProgress;
        job.Spin();
        return true;
    }

    void job_OnProgress(int percent)
    {
        _progressForm.UpdateProgress(percent);
    }
}

class LongJob
{
    public event Progressed OnProgress;
    public delegate void Progressed(int percent);

    public void Spin()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(25);
            if (OnProgress != null)
            {
                OnProgress(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Win32Window : IWin32Window
{
    private readonly IntPtr _hwnd;
    public Win32Window(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return _hwnd;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@StephenCleary's answer is correct. Though, I had to make a little modification to his answer to get the behavior what I think OP wants.

```
public void GoAsync() //no longer async as it blocks on Appication.Run
{
    var owner = new Win32Window(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
    _progressForm = new Form1();

    var progress = new Progress<int>(value => _progressForm.UpdateProgress(value));

    _progressForm.Activated += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            await Go(progress);
            _progressForm.Close();
        };

    Application.Run(_progressForm);
}
```

Comment: if Go(progress) throw an exception, then _progressForm.Close() will never be called -> the modal dialog will hang forever

Comment: And It's better to change "_progressForm.Activated" to "_progressForm .Shown" because _progressForm might be activated multiple times during his life time.. -> Go(progress) will be called multiple times..

Answer (score 20):

The `async` and `await` keywords do not mean "run on a background thread." I have an [`async`/`await` intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that describes what they *do* mean. You must explicitly place CPU-bound operations on a background thread, e.g., `Task.Run`.

Also, the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) documentation describes the common approaches with `async` code, e.g., progress reporting.

```
class Manager
{
  private static Form1 _progressForm;

  public async Task GoAsync()
  {
    var owner = new Win32Window(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
    _progressForm = new Form1();
    _progressForm.Show(owner);

    var progress = new Progress<int>(value => _progressForm.UpdateProgress(value));
    await Go(progress);

    _progressForm.Hide();
  }

  private Task<bool> Go(IProgress<int> progress)
  {
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var job = new LongJob();
      job.Spin(progress);
      return true;
    });
  }
}

class LongJob
{
  public void Spin(IProgress<int> progress)
  {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(25);
      if (progress != null)
      {
        progress.Report(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `Progress<T>` type properly handles thread marshaling, so there's no need for marshaling within `Form1.UpdateProgress`.

Comment: Your changes are not producing the desired results. Since OP is running in a `Console` application, there is no `SynchronizationContext`. I think it needs to be introduced for `Progress<T>` to work correctly?

Comment: Windows Forms components will establish a `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` when they are created, and `Progress<T>` does not require a `SynchronizationContext` (though it does work better with one).

Comment: I put a break point into the delegate passed to `Progress<T>` - it never gets hit - UI just hangs although the job is spinning. I thought `Application.Run()` was required to establish `SynchronizationContext` - does `_progressForm.Show` establish one? I am not sure.

Comment: I believe there's a `SynchronizationContext` but no main loop. `Main` would have to call `Application.Run`, `ShowDialog`, or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `SynchronizationContext` is there - but no loop to  process things `Posted/Send` to it. Hence my break point wont hit. Thanks.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Anyone reading this: the 100% complete solution is this post plus the "accepted" from YK1.

Comment: Excellent blog post, BTW. That cleared a few things up immensely.

Answer (score 6):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar1.Value = value; });
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            progress.Report(i);
    });
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to be the easiest way to update a progress bar.