# How to implement a progress bar in windows forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker, implementation

I have my own solution to import monthly sales data in my windows form application. When a user click on `import` button, the program is actually running but it looks like it's not responding. The process takes a long time about 5 minutes.

So, I'd like to implement a progress bar with status strip label to display as an user interface and let the users know how much the task is done. This is also my first time using a progress bar in my program. So, I read through some tutorials which show how to use it. Some people use progress bar with background worker and timer.

But I don't understand where I should use the solution that I have. In background worker `DoWork()` event? I don't want to fake it by abusing the progress bar like setting the progressBar.Maximum = 100, progressBar.Value = 0 and as long as the timer is ticking increasing the value by 5. The progress bar must report the actual progress while the program is running.

The following is the solution I am using now to import the data:

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lsbxBrowsedFiles.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            ArrayList salesHeaderArr = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList salesDetailArr = new ArrayList();

            int i = 0;
            while (i < browsedXmlFileList.Count)
            {
                if (browsedXmlFileList[i].ToUpper().EndsWith("SALESHEADER.XML"))
                {
                    salesHeaderArr.Add(browsedXmlFileList[i]);
                }
                if (browsedXmlFileList[i].ToUpper().EndsWith("SALESDETAIL.XML"))
                {
                    salesDetailArr.Add(browsedXmlFileList[i]);
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (selectedFileIsNotInDestinationFolder(salesHeaderArr, salesDetailArr) == true)
            {
                i = 0;
                while (i < salesHeaderArr.Count)
                {
                    SalesHeader salesHeader = new SalesHeader();
                    string sourceFilePath = salesHeaderArr[i].ToString();
                    readXMLFiles(sourceFilePath, SALES_HEADER);
                    SalesHeader salesCheck = (SalesHeader)salesHeaderList[0];
                    string checkOutletCode = salesCheck.OutletCode;
                    DateTime checkBusDate = salesCheck.BusinessDate.Value;
                    if (SalesHeader.IsThisRowAlreadyImportedInSalesHeader(checkOutletCode, checkBusDate) == false)
                    {
                        salesHeader.ImportSalesHeader(salesHeaderList);
                        salesHeader.CreateImportDataLog(getDestinationFilePath(sourceFilePath),
                            DateTime.Now, salesHeaderList.Count, SALES_HEADER);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string errorDate = checkBusDate.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy");
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected XML File with BusinessDate: " + errorDate + " has been already imported.",
                            "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select a file which has not been imported!",
                            "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                        return;
                    }
                    MoveXMLFiletoDestinationFolder(sourceFilePath);
                    i++;
                }
                i = 0;
                while (i < salesDetailArr.Count)
                {
                    SalesDetail salesDetail = new SalesDetail();
                    string sourceFilePath = salesDetailArr[i].ToString();
                    readXMLFiles(sourceFilePath, SALES_DETAIL);
                    SalesDetail salesCheck = (SalesDetail)salesDetailList[0];
                    string checkOutletCode = salesCheck.OutletCode;
                    DateTime checkBusDate = salesCheck.BusinessDate.Value;
                    if (SalesDetail.IsThisRowAlreadyImportedInSalesDetail(checkOutletCode, checkBusDate) == false)
                    {
                        salesDetail.ImportSalesDetail(salesDetailList);
                        salesDetail.GenerateCarryForward(salesDetailList);
                        salesDetail.CalculateImportInventoryBalance(salesDetailList);
                        salesDetail.CreateImportDataLog(getDestinationFilePath(sourceFilePath), DateTime.Now, salesDetailList.Count, SALES_DETAIL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string errorDate = checkBusDate.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy");
                        MessageBox.Show("Selected XML File with BusinessDate: " + errorDate + " has been already imported.",
                            "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select a file which has not been imported!",
                            "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                        return;
                    }
                    MoveXMLFiletoDestinationFolder(sourceFilePath);
                    i++;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Import has been successfully completed!",
                "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                clearListBoxItems();
                lblMessage.Visible = false;
            }
            //Abort the import operation here!
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a file which has not been imported!",
                "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
                clearListBoxItems();
                lblMessage.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select XML files to import!", 
                "ABC Cafe Import Sales Wizard");
        }
    }
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Consider using async/await constructs for simplicity. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar)

Comment: Just plop a progressbar down, at the start of your method set the progress bars `Maximum` property to the amount of files you will be iterating through, every time you iterate through a file add one to the progress bars `Value` property. If the program doesn't respond or show progress each iteration use an `Application.DoEvents()` call after each file iteration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has many loops,since it will be difficult to get the increment value and increment the progress bar value in each loop iteration.You could set the progress bar maximum to 100,Then divide 100 by the number of loops you have say X.

So the trick would be to fill the progress bar by this value when each loops completes

and yes you should put this code in backgroundworker's `DoWork()` otherwise it will freeze the form.Also there is no need for a timer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can you provide some example for doing this? I am a bit confused. There are only 2 loops in this case. SalesHeader & SalesDetail. In each loop, I use `int percents = ((i + 1) * 100) / salesDetailArr.Count;` to get the percentage and `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percents, i);` to report progress. However, It doesn't report back to `backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` method and progress bar increment remains at 0. Inside the second loop, when the program executes the ImportSalesDetail() method, it increases to 50. May I know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Have you added the delegate.I suggest you remove the % thing and go on with the method i have suggested. Although it might not display exact progress,it does report progress and there is no need for 'backgroundWorker.ReportProgress'

Comment: I marked your answer as a correct answer. I used this formula to find the progress percentage. `int findPercentage = ((i + 1) * 100) / salesHeaderArr.Count;` from this, I get the progress percentage. `progress = 0` I reset the progress to 0. `progress += findPercentage / 2;` There are 2 loops in my program. So, I divided by 2. So, if the first loop completes running, I will get 50%. In another loop. I use the same formula but here 'progress += (findPercentage / 2) + 50;' I added 50 from the first loop. Now with your help, I have finished my implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have used `Progress Bar` in my application.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += (se, eventArgs) => {
            this.progressBar.Maximum = 100;
            this.progressBar.Minimum = 0;
            this.progressBar.Value = eventArgs.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = eventArgs.UserState as String;
            lblPercentage.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", eventArgs.ProgressPercentage);
        };

worker.DoWork += (se, eventArgs) => {
    int progress = 0;
    ((BackgroundWorker)se).ReportProgress(progress, "Initializing the files...");

    //Process that takes a long time
    //Formula to calculate Progress Percentage 
    //This is how I calculated for my program. Divide 100 by number of loops you have

    int findPercentage = ((i + 1) * 100) / salesHeaderArr.Count;
    progress = 0;
    progress += findPercentage / 2;

    //Report back to the UI
    string progressStatus = "Importing Sales Header... (" + getSourceFileName(sourceFilePath) + ")";     
    ((BackgroundWorker)se).ReportProgress(progress, progressStatus);

   //After Iterating through all the loops, update the progress to "Complete"
   ((BackgroundWorker)se).ReportProgress(100, "Complete...");
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (se, eventArgs) =>
        {
            //Display smth or update status when progress is completed
            lblStatus.Location = new Point(20, 60);
            lblStatus.Text = "Your import has been completed. \n\nPlease Click 'Finish' button to close the wizard or \n'Back' button to go back to the previous page.";
            lblPercentage.Visible = false;
            progressBar.Visible = false;
            btnBack.Enabled = true;
            btnFinish.Enabled = true;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `i` from?

Comment: @SiKni8 You can find it in my question. `i` is used as an iteration in `SalesHeader` and `SalesDetail` loops. The formula I have used in my solution works in this way. If you have 2 loops, divide your percentage by 2. After first loop, you will have 50% of your process. In second loop, use the same formula but add 50 from your first loop.

Comment: Oooops didn't realize you answered your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ManualResetEvent, Now while you are processing, let the Progressbar Increase until it meets a certain point and wait for a Set.

Example:

you have this 2 fields

```
private int progress = 0;
private ManualResetEvent reset = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
// Sets it to unsignalled
private ManualResetEvent reset2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);

while(progress  < 40)
{
   progress ++;
}

reset.WaitOne();

while(progress < 90)
{
   progress ++;
}

reset2.WaitOne();

while(progress < 100)
{
   progress ++;
}
```

// This finishes the progress, Now on your actual Work, you have to signal those wait.

```
DoWork()
{
   // long process here. . . .

   reset.Set();

   // Another long process

   reset2.Set();
}
```

Comment: didn't i just gave you an example? its declared on the class, now on your backgroundworker, run the while loop and after reaching a certain value, use the manualresetevent to waitone, and then on your actual process set it if you want the progressbar to process.

Please read it and absorb it >.>, i just gave the answer and you're asking me for more work?