# Progress Bar Implementation in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I tried to implement progressbar in windows form but progress bar is showing result after completion of whole execution.

```
 public Status()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (ForReporting.FileProcessed <= ForReporting.TotalNumberFiles)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            int temp=ForReporting.FileProcessed*100;
            temp = temp / ForReporting.TotalNumberFiles;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(temp);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Status_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: ForReporting is Static class contain Static Variable TotalNumberFiles and FilesProcessed.

Comment: TotalNumberFiles give the total number of file and FilesProcessed constantly increase. depends how many files processed till now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a progress bar in windows forms C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971829/how-to-implement-a-progress-bar-in-windows-forms-c)

Comment: Using simple `Debug.WriteLine()` messages you should be able to tell whether `ReportProgress(temp)` is called once or multiple times, and whether the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event occurs multiple times.

Comment: Your posted code never increments the FileProcessed value, so it's always zero.

Comment: value of FileProcessed continuously increasing in our part of program.