# Async/Await with a WinForms ProgressBar - WinForms version

Tags: c#, asynchronous, progress-bar, async-await

Please see: http://codepaste.net/djw3cw  for the code

If it's true that async/await for asynchronous programming will soon be like Linq, I think this question is a non-trivial extension of [Async/Await with a WinForms ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar)

I would be greatful for a pointer or an answer in words in lieu of code, though code is optimal.

The issue is this:  how to set up a progress bar to work using asynch/await.  In the past I've used a Dispatcher successfully.

```
Please see: http://codepaste.net/djw3cw  for the code
What is done: a textbox has any text in it converted to an int, then when
"mybutton1" is clicked, work is done based on the int, for int ms (int = 
milliseconds).
During this time, a progressbar "myProgressBar" is shown for 
every tenth-percent step
When work is complete, the label/textblock controls are updated
But the below does not work right: the form simply freezes until the work is
complete.  How to fix it?
How to do this using Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) or Async/Await,
rather than a Dispatcher?
```

Here is a snippet of the code in question, self-explanatory.

```
 private void mybutton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.Content = myTextBox.Text;

        string myString = myTextBox.Text;

        bool result = Int32.TryParse(myString, out myInteger);

        if (result == true)
        {
        myTextblock.Text = "Success, thread will be delayed by: " +  myInteger.ToString() + " ms";

            //
            int CounterInteger = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < myInteger; j++) // set # itt
            {

                Thread.Sleep(1); //do some work here

               // myClassDoWork1.Delay_DoWork(myInteger); //optional way to do work in another class...

                if (j % (myInteger / 10) == 0)  //display progress bar in 10% increments
                {

                    CounterInteger = CounterInteger + 10;
                     myProgressBar.Value = (double)CounterInteger; // won't work here in a parallel manner...must use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Action 
                    //how to make this work using Async/Await?  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar

                }

            }
            ///
            /// // above does not work properly:  the form simply freezes until the work is complete.  How to fix it?
            ///


            myLabel.Content = "done, delayed work done successfully: in " + myInteger.ToString() + " milliseconds";
            myTextblock.Text = "done, delayed work done successfully: in " + myInteger.ToString() + " milliseconds";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            myTextblock.Text = "Error, integer not entered, try again." + myTextBox.Text;
            myLabel.Content = "Error, integer not entered, try again.";
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please edit the code into your question - ideally edited to be as short as possible while still being complete and demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Hi Jon--I actually am reading your book on this topic "C# In Depth".  Do you see the code at CodePaste OK? I find that cutting and pasting code here does not work very well for me, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I can see the code at CodePaste - but it's simply not a good way of asking a question. It's worth becoming familiar with the Stack Overflow markdown editor (and preview window) - formatting your question clearly (and not just linking to code offsite) is important in creating a good question.

Comment: OK let me try again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have any `async` or `await` in your code. The reason your UI thread is blocking is because you're running synchronous code on it.

If you have CPU-bound code that you want to push off to a background thread, use `Task.Run`. Then you can `await` that code from the UI thread.

```
private async void mybutton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  myLabel.Content = myTextBox.Text;
  string myString = myTextBox.Text;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(myString, out myInteger);

  if (result == true)
  {
    myTextblock.Text = "Success, thread will be delayed by: " +  myInteger.ToString() + " ms";
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => { myProgressBar.Value = value; });
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      int CounterInteger = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < myInteger; j++)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        if (j % (myInteger / 10) == 0)
        {
          CounterInteger = CounterInteger + 10;
          progress.Report(CounterInteger);
        }
      }
    }

    myLabel.Content = "done, delayed work done successfully: in " + myInteger.ToString() + " milliseconds";
    myTextblock.Text = "done, delayed work done successfully: in " + myInteger.ToString() + " milliseconds";
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    myTextblock.Text = "Error, integer not entered, try again." + myTextBox.Text;
    myLabel.Content = "Error, integer not entered, try again.";
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Unfortunately I just realized that I'm not using .NET Framework 4.0 not 4.5 so these features are not showing up in IntelliSense.

Comment: In that case you can install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`.