# Async-Await Progress Bar and Cross Threading Issue

Tags: c#, async-await

I've been working on a progress bar with async and await in C#. I made a simple form `Form1.cs` with the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress> progress;
    public Form1(Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress> progress = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (progress == null)
        {
            this.progress = new Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress>();
        }
        else
        {
            this.progress = progress;
        }

        this.progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");

            progressBar.Value += e.ProgressPercentage;

            txtResult.Text += e.Text;
        };

        Shown += async (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => HardTask(progress));
                txtResult.Text += "Done!";
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                Close();
            }
        };
    }

    void HardTask(Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress> progress)
    {
        incrementProgress();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    public void incrementProgress()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var args = new TaskAsyncExProgress();
                args.ProgressPercentage = 1;
                args.Text = i.ToString() + " "; 
                ((IProgress<TaskAsyncExProgress>)progress).Report(args);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        );
    }
}


public class TaskAsyncExProgress
{
    public int ProgressPercentage { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Program.cs`, I have two cases:

```
// Case 1: This causes a cross-thread issue
//Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress> progress = new Progress<TaskAsyncExProgress>();
//Form1 frm =  new Form1(progress);

// Case 2: This works fine
Form1 frm =  new Form1();

frm.ShowDialog();
```

Why is it that Case 1 causes a cross-threading issue, but Case 2 works fine? I feel like Case 1 could be a pretty useful construct if you want to use the `Report` method outside of the form itself.

Edit: I know that I can use a BeginInvoke or similar, but I was under the impression that Async+Await were supposed to make it so that I don't need to do that anymore.

Comment: Most of the explanation and working sample available in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar (almost duplicate). The exact problem (creating Progress *before* synchronization context created) answered by Servy (also there are many similar questions there is no good duplicate target yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Progress` class captures the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` when it's created, and uses that (or the default sync context if there is no value) to post the progress changed event handlers.

In your first example you're creating the `Progress` instance before the synchronization context is created.  In the second example you're creating it *after* the sync context is created, which is why it works.

Comment: Does that mean a `SynchronizationContext` is created upon making a form?

Comment: @Ringil No, it's created when you start the message loop.  Generally you should be using `Application.Run` to start your application loops, although you're using `ShowDialog` instead.

Comment: Well, I was trying to make a simple example to debug this issue in another problem. That other program uses ShowDialog, but I suppose that does not matter as that also creates a message loop.

Answer (score 0):

Updates made to the UI must take place in UI thread. Consider this:

```
this.progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInovoke(() => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");

            progressBar.Value += e.ProgressPercentage;

            txtResult.Text += e.Text;
        });
    };
```

**EDIT:** This applies to all UI updates, not only in this particural event.

Comment: Isn't Async-Await supposed to mean that you don't have to do Invokes?

Comment: @Ringil Yes, it is.  Sadly too many people, including this answerer, don't actually understand that and are stuck in the past, and insist on using extremely outdated and inferior tools for this task.

Comment: This isn't explaining why the second snippet works perfectly fine (as that is how these tools are supposed to be used; this answer is not.)  The whole point of using `Progress` is so that you don't have to explicitly invoke.

Comment: Async - await has nothing to do with dispatcher. The issue is to dispatch an action to the UI thread. If you want to wait for this action asynchronously, you can, just use `InvokeAsync`. However you are still stuck with a need to pass a delegate. The best would be to implement a custom awaiter that will make the continuation be dispatched, but it's far beyond this question.

Comment: See this as a reference for the comment above: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx

Comment: @MichałKędrzyński `await` most certainly has something to do with the dispatcher.  When you `await` something the current synchronization context is captured, and in a WPF application that'll be a wrapper for the `Dispatcher`, which will result in the continuation being posted to that sync context, which will post it to the dispatcher.  There is no need for a custom awaiter to do any of this.  Also note that the OP appears to be using a winform app, not a WPF app, so there is no dispatcher.  Fortunately `await` and `Progress` aren't dependent on such details, unlike your code.

Comment: Didn't know, that `Progress` captures `SynchronizationContext` to dispatch events, point for you. However without this, I see no reasonable alternative for "outdated and inferior tools" like explicit invoking dispatcher. I'm not familiar with winforms, but threading model in WPF is quite inconsistent and could be better, btw.

Comment: good info @Servy. What happens if your await starts from an external API and not your UI? Does that mean you still have to do that invoke nonsense if you want to bring the data back to the UI?

Comment: @vidalsasoon It's all going to depend on the specifics of the situation, but in the vast majority of cases, no.  If you have an API that represents an asynchronous operation that doesn't provide a `Task`, leaving you with an event/callback/etc. then you'd want to first transform it into a `Task` (how would depend on what, specifically, it is doing) so that you can then `await` it from the UI thread.  In certain very unlikely situations doing so may not be practical, and so you'd want to capture the UI's synchronization context and use that to start a new thread that will run in the UI context.