# Update UI from awaited method of another class in universal windows application

Tags: c#, user-interface, async-await, uwp

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to write a code that does serial communications with another hardware.
I'm using async/await to do the job. but I want to update a progress bar from the awaited method considering that my method is in another class called class1 and exists in class1.cs file attached to the solution.
I have one textblock, one progress bar and one start button in XAML code.

**How can I update "progressbar1" from "DummyWork" method in "Class1" class?**

I would appreciate if someone can help me in this matter.
My template code is as follows.

MainPage.xaml.cs  contents:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Threading;
using uwptestapp1classes;

namespace uwptestapp1
{ 
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {       
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            textBlock.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private async void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int asyncResult = 0;
            progressbar1.Value = 0;
            startBtn.IsEnabled = false;
            textBlock.Text += "button press log: " + startBtn.Content + " button is pressed" + Environment.NewLine;
            DateTime previousTime = DateTime.Now;
            asyncResult = await Task.Run(() => Class1.DummyWork(previousTime));
            textBlock.Text += "Task have been done" + Environment.NewLine;
            startBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Class1.cs contents:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Threading;

namespace uwptestapp1classes
{
    public  class Class1
    {
               public static int DummyWork(DateTime previoustime)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100;)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - previoustime).Milliseconds >= 500)
                {
                    /* UI update code
                     * update "progressbar1.value"
                     */
                    previoustime = DateTime.Now;
                }

                //delay without using task.delay
                for (int myCounter = 0; myCounter < 50000000;)
                {
                    myCounter++;
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for your comment. I updated by my exact question.

Comment: [Seems like you haven't done much research on this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=uwp+progress+bar+from+task+c%23). Have you?

Comment: [This post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar) cover all you need for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To report progress from a piece of code, you should use `IProgress<T>`:

```
public  class Class1
{
  public static int DummyWork(DateTime previoustime, IProgress<DateTime> progress = null)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100;)
    {
      if ((DateTime.Now - previoustime).Milliseconds >= 500)
      {
        progress?.Report(DateTime.Now);
      }

      //delay without using task.delay
      for (int myCounter = 0; myCounter < 50000000;)
      {
        myCounter++;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }
}
```

To receive progress, you can use `Progress<T>`:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{       
  private async void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    int asyncResult = 0;
    progressbar1.Value = 0;
    startBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    textBlock.Text += "button press log: " + startBtn.Content + " button is pressed" + Environment.NewLine;
    DateTime previousTime = DateTime.Now;
    var progress = new Progress<DateTime>(time =>
    {
      progressbar1.value = ...;
    });
    asyncResult = await Task.Run(() => Class1.DummyWork(previousTime, progress));
    textBlock.Text += "Task have been done" + Environment.NewLine;
    startBtn.IsEnabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.
what does "?" mean in `progress?.Report(DateTime.Now);`?

Comment: It means to only call `Report` if `progress` is not `null`.